# Sending a function into a matlab function

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm trying build a matlab function that will evaluate a function and vector that are sent in as parameters.  I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to send in the function so that it can be evaluated in the matlab function.  I figured out how to do it without the function but I'm a little lost trying to evaluate it within a matlab function.  Below is my code...

This is what I'm trying to do...

```
x = [x1 x2]';
f = x(x1)^2 + 2 * (x2)^2

x = [5 10];
f = (5)^2 + 2 * (10)^2 % which I would like to return 225, not a column vector
```

This is what I have and what I have tried...

```
x = [5 10]';

% without using a matlab function
% k = 1
% f = x(k)^2 + 2 * x(k + 1)^2;   % returns the correct answer of 225

f = x^2 + 2 * x^2       % complains about the scalar 2
f = x.^2 + 2 * x.^2     % returns a column vector [75; 300]
function [value] = evalFunction(f,x)
value = f(x);
```

I've tried...

```
f = @(x) x.^2 + 2 * (x+1).^2;
value = evalFunction(@f,x)      %Error: "f" was previously used as a variable
```

So I tried...

```
f = @(x) x.^2 + 2 * (x+1).^2;
value = evalFunction(f,x)       %value = [97;342]
```

I'm new to matlab so any help is appreciated.  I've been doing some research and found some stuff here on stackoverflow but can't seem to get it to work.  I've seen there are other ways to do this, but I will eventually be adding more code to the matlab evalFunction function so I'd like to do it this way.  Thanks!

Comment: Note the difference between `[1 2]^2` (which tries to do matrix multiplication on a row vector, and will throw an error) and `[1 2].^2` which performs `element-by-element multiplication` - result is `[1*1 2*2]` or `[1 4]`. Besides that - "function handles" is indeed the thing you need to learn about. @chappj's answer contains links that should help.

Comment: I updated the question to make more sense and not ask the proper question at the end :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) plus array indexing.  Taking `x` as a 2-element vector, define and use your function like:

```
f = @(x) x(1).^2 + 2 * x(2).^2;
value = evalFunction(f,x) % but you can just do f(x) if that is all you need
```

However, if `evalFunction` does nothing other than evaluate `f` at `x`, then you don't need it at all.  Just do `f(x)`.

Alternately,

```
f = @(x1,x2) x1.^2 + 2*x2.^2;
value = evalFunction(f,x1,x2); % here your function will call it by f(x1,x2)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was as clear as I wanted to be.  Please see the updated question and thanks again for the help.

Comment: Upvoting this for the useful information / links , and "heavy lifting" to actually get the question into a shape where it could be answered...

Comment: Thanks for the help and putting up with my very metamorphic question :>

Answer (score 3):

You are probably coming at this from a C background - in Matlab, `x+1` is the entire vector `x` with `1` added - not the element offset by 1.

The function you need is

```
f = @(x)x(1).^2 + 2 * (x(2)).^2;
```

or, to be a little more "matlab-like":

```
f = @(x) [1 2] * x(1:2)'.^2;
```

Which performs the element-wise square of the first two elements of `x` as a column vector, and then does the matrix multiplication with `[1 2]`, resulting in

```
1 * x(1) .^2 + 2 * x(2) .^2;
```

Which seems to be what you were asking for.

*caveat*: did not have opportunity to test this...

Comment: Yeah, we both arrived at the answer, finally.  Everything after "I've tried..." in the question was from back-and-forth with my answer.  The question was quite metamorphic.  :)

Comment: @chappjc - indeed. Hence my vote for your answer (although I prefer my matrix multiplication method of getting the dot product of individual squares and coefficients).

Comment: Thanks for the help this was very useful!  I did change my question to make more sense.  And you are right that I am coming from a C background.